# Newly created PHP Composer Package, once installed into another app, will not download the composer package dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I have had about a 6 year hiatus from coding.

I am currently for my own benefit of understanding, reminding myself the process of creating Composer packages.

I have created a simple package that has 1 dependency.
It works stand alone. Pulls it in and runs the tests.

I created a new app for testing.
I gave the app the location of my new package as a dependency.

It works - it pulls it in and semi-runs.

I say semi, because it does not pull in the packages 1 dependency that it has.

Im sure this is one of the face-plant occasions but I can't remember what im doing wrong.

Would really appreciate pointing in the right direction.

This is the packages `composer.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "sidekick/config",
 
  "minimum-stability": "stable",

  "require": {
    "vlucas/phpdotenv" : ">=5.4"

  },


  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "SideKick\\Config\\": "src"
    }
  }

}
```

This is the `composer.json` file of MyApp.

```json
{
    "name": "myapp/package-tester",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\PackageTester\\": "src/"
        }
    },
   
    "require": {
        "sidekick/config": "dev-master"
    },

    "minimum-stability": "stable",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "sidekick/config",
                "version":"dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "prob-best-to-keep-private-for-now",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["/"]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, here is the class map produced by composer and a grab of the vendor directory:

```
return array(
    'Composer\\InstalledVersions' => $vendorDir . '/composer/InstalledVersions.php',
    'SideKick\\Config\\Config' => $vendorDir . '/sidekick/config/src/Config.php',
);
```

[grab of vendor directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRFUx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Composer has a couple of commands you can normally use for trouble-shooting, no need to deduce from the class-map/autoloader <sup>1</sup>.

**`composer show`** (just that). What I like about it is that if you pull in from your own repositories it shows the git commit hashes. with git you then can show the composer.json file at that revision:

**`git show`** that is, `git -C <repo-path> show <rev>:composer.json` and then some [`jq(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/jq/jq.1.en.html). Example from some project linking in local git repositories:

```
$ composer show                                                
hakre/json-pointer        dev-wip/bin e476125 JSON Text and JSON Pointer PHP library (data driven).
hakre/tunesmith           1.0.0               Tunesmith - noun; informal - A composer of popular musi...
roave/security-advisories dev-latest 9edb62e  Prevents installation of composer packages with known s...

$ git -C ../JsonPointer show e476125:composer.json | jq '.require'
{
  "php": "^5.3.3 || ^7.0 || ^8.0",
  "ext-json": "*"
}
```

Here the dependency project is installed from an older revision that has not yet any other requirements than platform packages.

Most often this finds the problem you describe pretty fast.

**`composer why`** and **`why-not`** can also help when dealing with requirement resolution, albeit in this case asking for *Why not?* for a package composer yet doesn't see any requirement for does not make much sense. I just mention them as you for perhaps the next problems that arise, like version conflicts or you just want to know.

---

1. Remark on trouble-shooting by the composer autoloader: Yes, I know it works and I'm sometimes also doing it, but have found out that best only when I need to trouble-shoot actual autoloading issues, not the "require" issues as mentioned. Reading the `vendor/composer` directory is hard with its many files and especially from the autoloader.